# What does a combination "&" with " -" mean?

Tags: c

Does anyone know what does `&-` in C programming?

`limit= address+ (n &- sizeof(uint));`

Comment: `&` bitwise and operator; `-` unary minus operator

Comment: To understand, try different spacing: `limit = address + (n & -sizeof(uint));`

Comment: Same as `n & ( - sizeof(uint))`

Comment: @Adil.Kolenko You can meet even the following operator &-- or &++ in C.:) Or for example operator +++ or ---.:) New operators in C appear due to a bad programming style.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow `if (!limit) return;`, in this case `!` , is it bitwise NOT?

Comment: @Adil.Kolenko ! is the logical negation operator.

Comment: bitwise not is `~`; `!` is logical not ... `!a` or `!!a` is either `0` or `1` whatever the type and value of `a`

Comment: @pmg What does `if (!limit) return;` mean?

Comment: same as `if (limit == 0) return;` with the proper `0` of the right kind to be compared with `limit` (maybe it's good enough to rely on compiler doing the right conversion if needed).

Comment: It typically means that you are reading some joke code. Similarly `-->` and `+++` operators don't exist either.

Comment: @Lundin does it mean all comments are wrong? `&-` -command doesnt exist?

Comment: @Adil.Kolenko `&-` is not a "command" or an operator - it's just poorly spaced code. **Usually** people would write the code with a space between the `&` and the `-` - Lundin means that writing the code like `&-` is usually done as a joke (or code golf, or whatever). Similarly, `-->` is usually written as `-- >` (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642028/what-is-the-operator-in-c-c?rq=1)

Comment: IMO code like `limit= address+ (n &- sizeof(uint));` is probably from a programmer trying to show off by being *clever*.  As in, "Look at my *clever* code!  I wrote it, and you can't figure it out! Aren't I *clever*!"  Nope, you're not.  Truly brilliant code evokes responses like, "That's so easy and obvious!  Why didn't I think of that?" and not "WTF is this?!?!"  Code that evokes the latter - as in this case - isn't *clever*.  It's **STUPID**.  It's bug-prone and wastes time and effort both upon creation and when someone tries to understand it. Making things harder is the opposite of clever.

Comment: @AndrewHenle The most accurate code quality metric is [WTF/minute](https://i2.wp.com/commadot.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/02/wtf.png?resize=550%2C433) :)

Comment: @AndrewHenle is there simple version of the code in the post (`limit= address+ (n &- sizeof(uint));`)? Can I rewrite it ?

Answer (score 11):

This isn't really one operator, but two:

```
(n) & (-sizeof(uint))
```

i.e. this is performing a bitwise and operation between `n` and `-sizeof(uint)`.

---

What does this mean?

Let's assume `-sizeof(uint)` is `-4` - then by two's complement representation, `-sizeof(uint)` is `0xFFFFFFFC` or

```
1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1100
```

We can see that this bitwise and operation will zero-out the last two bits of `n`. This effectively aligns `n` to the lowest multiple of `sizeof(uint)`.

Comment: it *does not* depend two complement. Unary `-` of `unsigned` is `unsigned`. See 6.5.3.3p3. Next according to 6.3.1.3p2 the result will set to *unsinged* `2^N-4` which is `111...1100` independently of representation of signed integers. (N - is number of bits in `unsigned`)

Comment: @tstanisl Hehe, cool! Though I'm not entirely sure that this means that we can assume the value will be `1111...1100` - at any rate I'm leaving two's complement in the answer because I think it's relevant for beginners' understanding. I'll edit your comment in, thanks :)

Comment: 6.3.1.3p basically says that negative values are converted to unsigned by repeatedly adding UINT_MAX (i.e. 2^32) until it gets into `0..UINT_MAX-1` range. And unsigned numbers have natural encoding for binary numbers.

Comment: @tstanisl In this case `SIZE_MAX`. But also note that `UINT_MAX` is defined as 2^n - 1 so in range will be `0...UINT_MAX`.

Comment: @Lundin, you're right. I've meant adding SIZE_MAX+1

Answer (score 3):

`&-` is the binary bitwise AND operator written together with `-` which is the unary minus operator. Operator precedence (binary `&` having lowest precedence here) gives us the operands of `&` as `n` and `-sizeof(uint)`.

The purpose is to create a bit mask in a very obscure way, relying on unsigned integer arithmetic. Assuming `uint` is 4 bytes (don't use homebrewed types either btw, use `stdint.h`), then the code is equivalent to this

```
n & -(size_t)4
```

`size_t` being the type returned by `sizeof`, which is guaranted to be a large, unsigned integer type. Applying unary minus on unsigned types is of course nonsense too. Though even if it is obscure, applying minus on unsigned arithmetic results in well-defined wrap-around<sup>1)</sup>, so in case of the value `4`, we get `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFC` on a typical PC where `size_t` is 64 bits.

`n & 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFC` will mask out everything but the 2 least significant bits.

What the relation between these 2 bits and the size of the type used is, I don't know. I *guess* that the purpose is to store something equivalent to the type's size in bytes in that area. Something with 4 values will fit in the two least significant bits: binary 0, 1, 10, 11. (The purpose could maybe be masking out misaligned addresses or some such?)

Assuming I guessed correct, we can write the same code without any obfuscation practices as far more readable code:

```
~(sizeof(uint32_t)-1)
```

Which gives us `4-1 = 0x3`, `~0x3 = 0xFFFF...FC`. Or in case of 8 byte types, `0xFFFF...F8`. And so on.

So I'd rewrite the code as

```
#include <stdint.h>

uint32_t mask = ~(sizeof(uint32_t)-1);
limit = address + (n & mask);
```

---

<sup>1)</sup> C17 6.3.1.3

> Otherwise, if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by repeatedly adding or subtracting one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type until the value is in the range of the new type<sup>60)</sup>

Where the foot note 60) says:

> The rules describe arithmetic on the mathematical value, not the value of a given type of expression.

In this case repeatedly subtracting `SIZE_MAX+1` from 4 until the value is in range of what can fit inside a `size_t` variable.